# Rendering Options Missing

Tags: rendering, shaders, customization, antialiasing

In the rendering tab, I am missing numerous options such as anti-aliasing and shading. Is there a toggle in user preferences for expanded rendering options?

Comment: There are no anti-aliasing or shading options in Rendering tab of Properties Editor. They are not supposed to be there with Cycles rendering engine selected.

Answer (score 1):

Cycles rendering is different than the blender internal rendering (this applies for v2.79b and lower).

You can however acces the Anti-aliasing settings if you really want to. 

Under sampling enable branched path tracing and you should see the option for AA.

[image]

The Shading options also differ.
They are split into the world and object properties.

Everyting else you can probably edit via the node editor.

[image]